# How can the scale be projected correctly in Quantum GIS when it is imported from google earth (KML) files?

Tags: qgis, kml, scale, area, attribute-table

While importing KML files from google Earth to Quantum GIS, the scale is not being projected properly and the area of a particular selected feature is not being calculated in the attribute table by the field calculator. How can the area of a selected feature be calculated by the field calculator, as right now it is showing up zero as the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KMLs only support WGS84 CRS which uses degrees as unit of measurement. Field Calculator therefore calculates area in square degrees. If the polygons are small, the area will be almost zero.

Change to a different file format, reproject the data and calculate the area.

Comment: I have saved the file as an SHP. So can you please tell me how to reproject the data and calculate the area?

Comment: Pick the new target CRS in "Save as ..." dialog to reproject. Use Field Calculator $area operator to calculate the area.

Comment: Can you please tell what type of coordinate reference system should be used for India as I am unable to find the proper CRS that can be used in India?

Comment: WGS 84/World Mercator worked. So no problem. Thank you for resolving the earlier question.